# Including separate html file does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jquery to simply load another html file in my current html file, but nothing is showing. I tried following one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file), but I'm still not seeing anything appear on my html file.

**about.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js">
    $(function(){
      $("#topbar").load("b.html");
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="topbar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**b.html**

`<p> This is the included file </p>`

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JS `<script>` 101: You can either have a fully defined script inside the `<script>...</script>` block, **OR** you can load the script from an external `src`. You cannot have both in a single block. If you specify a `src`, then the body of the `<script>` block is ignored. You should have

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script> <-------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
$(function(){
  $("#topbar").load("b.html");
});
</script>
```

Note the `</script><script>` addition.

Comment: I added that addition, but there's nothing being displaying in about.html If I was to open it in a web browser

Comment: then check the js console for errors, check your webserver's access log to see if there's a hit on b.html at all, etc...

Comment: "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: ah, something something localhost I got it

Comment: @SyntacticFructose I bet you are opening your page on `file://`.

Comment: .load() is an ajax call, and can only be done if the containing page was loaded from the SAME source. file:// urls cannot do ajax requests to themselves, since they weren't loaded via an http request.

Answer (score -1):

try this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "b.html",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: { },
      success: function(data) {
          $("#topbar").html(data);
      }
    })      
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="topbar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```